# Configuring my web app to be used simultaneously

Tags: python, django, web

I am building a tic-tac-toe game using django. Different users will be simuntaneously playing the game at different places. So, how does the server store the states of game board for different persons?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on, as you haven't provided any code. Maybe try including the relevant pieces from your views?

Comment: You should create something like users and theirs game sessions.

Comment: How do I play the same game at two different places simuntaneously? At present, both the games are changing the same array where I am storing the states.

Comment: Well maybe it happens because you are doing it wrong way. Show us what you got and we can help you.

Comment: How are we supposed to find out what is wrong without the code ?

Comment: code has been included now

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your games. I would do this by making a `Game` model that has its own board. If you are planning to make this a multi-player app, I would also give the model `player1` and `player2` attributes so that you can determine which board to show to a particular user.

I don't have a great way to keep the games in sync across multiple tabs other than to have some javascript that refreshes the board at a certain interval.